# Collatz-type problems with known divergent trajectories

Tags: reference-request, collatz-conjecture

It is a well-known problem, known as Collatz problem, to determine whether iteratively applying the map $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}\text{ if $x$ is even and }f(x)=3x+1\text{ otherwise}$ on a positive integer $n$ always will give us $1$. One possibility for which this could not be true is if the sequence $(f^k(n))_{k\in\Bbb N}$ was diverging to infinity. There are no such $n$, and for what I know, it is believed there are none.

Looking at [this Math SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14569/the-5n1-problem) I was mildly surprised to find out that if we replace $3$ by $5$, there are (apparently) no known trajectories diverging to infinity.

This let me to the following question:

> Is there an odd integer $a$ and an integer $n$ such that it is known that iterating the map $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}\text{ if $x$ is even and }f(x)=ax+1\text{ otherwise}$ gives a sequence diverging to infinity?

Note that allowing $a$ even would make the problem trivial. I was considering extending this question to more general functions, but I couldn't fina a formulation which would sieve out trivial cases. Let me know in the comments if you know of an example of a diverging sequence which (in your opinion) counts as non-trivial.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, it is easy to see from examples with small numbers (for instance 5x+1, see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/717376/1714 and http://mathoverflow.net/a/200126/7710) , that in general there should be divergent sequences, however, as far as I know, no one example of this type of transformation is *known* to have divergent trajectories.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Yes, and actually, seeing some of these examples lead me to asking the question here.

Comment: Ah I see, I overlooked "reference-request" and misunderstand the focus of your question; sorry. Anyway, after J. Lagarias had stopped his engagement and his final bibliography did not contain such a result any such result must be very fresh and recently published at would be noticed quickly at least in wikipedia. So we can be pretty sure that such a definite knowledge does not yet exist.

Comment: Let's say, hypothetically, that one were to prove that there *exists* a pair $(a,n)$ such that the sequence starting at $n$ with multiplier $a$ diverges, but that the proof did not exhibit a particular such pair.  The way the question is posed, that would answer in the affirmative -- yet I strongly suspect that the real question is "has anybody produced a specific such pair and proven that it diverges?"

Comment: @MarkFischler You've guessed correctly that in mind I would like to see an explicit example, but if there were a nonconstructive proof (which I don't think you are claiming to have), I'd be very interested in hearing that as well.